# Linphone SDK wrong utf-8 Encoder

Tags: linphone, linphone-sdk

I'm using the Linphoe SDK for windows 10 version 5.1.21 (from https://download.linphone.org/releases/windows/sdk/).
when passing Non English characters thru the invite messages ("רונן" sip:2007@172.28.11.141;tag=1c1835228085) or in the notify body the characters received as Geeberish ("×¨×•× ×Ÿ" sip:2007@172.28.11.141).
In the Linphone logs it seems ok but get wrong encoding when received in the callbacks(onNotifyReceived).
this is not happening in Linphone SDK for Android nor iOS, only in UWP.
is there anyway solving it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We are aware of this issue and we are working on it.
In the meantime, you can try our `fix/xamarin-utf8-crash` SDK branch.

Cheers,